# UNIX grep - how to recusively find text in specifically-named files?

Tags: unix, grep

I would like a list of the filenames of files containing the word "hot" (don't care about case). The files should also be under the directory /test/home, with filenames **starting with** "config".

1. So far the best I can come up with is the following. However, it only works in the directory /test/home.

grep -ilrw "hot" * | grep -i config

Another disadvantage of this approach is that it is not possible to check for filenames starting with "config". For example, "grep -i ^config" will not match files such as "/test/home/configurations/config.xml"

Is there a way to work round this?

1. Could somebody please explain why the following does not work?

grep -ilrw "hot" config*

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -name 'config*' | xargs grep -i "hot"
```

may depend a bit on your flavor of UNIX, I think

Comment: Presuming that /test/home is the current directory of course; otherwise replace `.` with an actual path

Comment: Thank you. So is it correct to think that this operation cannot be achieved using the grep command alone?

Comment: Command should be find . -name 'config*' | xargs grep -ilw "hot". Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to use only grep you weren't far off. I'd do;

`grep -Rli --include='config*' "hot" *`

--include, allows you to specify a GLOB to search and the final * allows you to tweak the files/directories that the include glob will work on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know about this flag before. I think the command should be grep -Rl --include='config*' "hot" *

Comment: @Andy You'd be right! I've updated the command to include the l and i options you had.

Comment: Upvoting as OP seemed satisfied. @Andy, you should accept this answer if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a lucky user of GNU powertools, find can do that for you:

```
find /test/home -iregex ".*hot.*" -regex "config.*"
```

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have GNU powertools. Sorry!